# Enumeration of All Objects in An iOS Application

Tags: ios

For UIApplication, How to enumerate all the classes being instantiated?

```
for (NSObject *object in UIApplication.NSArray) {


}
```

I am not sure if that's correct way.

Comment: Do you mean, for every single object instantiated throughout the entire app?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that information?

Comment: Let say I have 10 custom classes, I would like to know how many of the 10 custom classes the app has instantiated.

Comment: This question will never help anyone. You have a lot of learning to do regarding objective c syntax and how to read the docs.  There is no quick answer that will help you.

Comment: You can get your custom classes but not their instances. You would need to implement your own autoreleasepool and use it. But if you have to ask, don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Your purpose is still unclear.  But I'll assume you're doing this for curiosity, debugging or profiling, because those are about the only sensible reasons to do this.  In any of those cases, use the [Allocations tool in Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH11-SW2).  You could mimic its functionality - the necessary SPIs are there in CoreFoundation, which is [mostly] open-source, and they're not that tricky.  But you really don't want to - they're not supported and not just liable to change, but *likely* to change in each major OS release.  And the Instruments user interface is quite powerful for analysing the volumes of data you'll be working with.

Answer (score 0):

You can give all of your custom classes a static variable counting the instances and a getter method to access that variable from other objects.